# SQL Query on find individuals that age is over 60 as of a specific date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Im new to stack so please go easy on me. Ive looked all over the web and cant find anything that really helps me.

So I need to provide details of all regular academics working in the Computing Department who were
over 60 years old as of 31/12/2014.

my trouble comes with how would I approach showing data of someone 60+ could you minus one date from another date? or is there is possible sql command that I am missing.

my attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM staff, department 
WHERE DOB <= '31/12/1964'
AND staff.department_ID = department.department _ID
```

Comment: please post your attempt

Comment: Appologies I'll remove MySQL and paste my attempt

Comment: You should not use implicit comma-separated joins. They got out of date when SQL-93 introduced explicit joins. (Oracle was very late to adopt them, though.) Use `FROM staff JOIN department ON ...` instead. A date literal in Oracle is written `date ' 1964-12-31'`. You are using a string literal instead relying on some regional settings to interpret that string as a date correctly. You shouldn't do that. Apart from that your query should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions to calculate the difference between dates, but the most efficient is to first calculate the date that a person would be born to be 60 at 2014-12-31. That way you make a direct comparison to a value, so the database can make use of an index if there is one.

Example for Oracle:

```
select
  PersonId, FirstName, LastName
from
  Person
where
  Born <= add_months(date '2014-12-31', -60 * 12)
```

Example for MySQL (eventhough you removed the MySQL tag):

```
select
  PersonId, FirstName, LastName
from
  Person
where
  Born <= date_sub('2014-12-31' 60 year)
```

Comment: That is very informative and a great help, thank you so much!

Comment: Downvoted because according to this, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm, Oracle does not have a dateadd function.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Updated the query. Here is where I found the dateadd function: http://sql-plsql.blogspot.se/2010/07/dateadd.html

Answer (score 0):

I think In SQL SERVER

Select Datediff(DAYS,'05-19-2015','05-21-2015')

In My SQL 
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time) 
           as `difference` FROM timeattendance WHERE timeattendance_id = '1484'

Answer (score 0):

The oracle add_months function will help you.

```
where yourfield < add_months(date '1964-12-31', 60*12 )
```

Comment: You are adding 60 years to 1964-12-31, which gives you 2024-12-31. At the time of writing this everyone alive is born before 2024.